# Rayleigh Quotient variant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming

If $A$ is a covariance matrix and I want to get

$\max X^TAX$ where each value of $x$ is between -1 and 1.

Is there a closed-form solution for this?

I understand when $X^TX = 1$ this becomes the original Rayleigh quotient problem.

Comment: Is $X$ a random column vector?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Right, X is an n x 1 vector